# PostgreSQL - GROUP BY condition, if a value is in one of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have sports teams with games. The games table has the following fields:

`home_id`, `away_id`

Where home_id and away_id are foreign keys relating to teams.

I want to somehow do an operation (GROUP BY?) where I get all of the games in which a team's ID is either in the away_id column or home_id column for all of the teams.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `GROUP BY` to achieve this. The query is pretty self explanatory:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE home_id = some_team_id OR away_id = some_team_id
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want. I want to do this for all teams in the teams table.

Comment: You should then rephrase your statement as something like "I want to get all the teams where ...".

Comment: "for all of the teams." I'm sorry for any misunderstanding. Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: @JGrishey . . . As I read the question this answers the question.  If you have another question, then ask another question, with sample data, desired results and a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand OP right he wanted the matrix below. Which he could filter:

```
t=# with s(game,home,away) as (values(1,1,2),(2,2,1),(3,2,3),(4,3,2),(5,1,5))
, m as (select unnest(array[home,away]) ar,game from s)
select ar team,count(1),array_agg(game) games from m group by ar order by ar;
 team | count |   games
------+-------+-----------
    1 |     3 | {2,5,1}
    2 |     4 | {4,3,1,2}
    3 |     2 | {3,4}
    5 |     1 | {5}
(4 rows)
```